# starting ruby on rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having problems starting my application.  Basically, I have an existing application, but just recently trying to test out ruby on another machine.  As such, I keep getting the welcome screen, even though I'm starting script/server in my application folder.

Any help to actually start my application would be much appreciated. I assume there is a rails path or something that needs to be set up look for the specific code, rather than just show the welcome rails webpage.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to delete your `public/index.html` file, and then setup a root map in the `routes.rb` file:

`map.root :controller => "pages", :action => "welcome"`

Comment: perfect, i totallllllly missed that :)

Comment: @user385948 You should click the checkmark that signifies this as a correct answer for a couple of reasons. 1. It's how things work around here and 2. To thank the person who took time out of his day to help you solve your problem.

Comment: @user385948 - Glad it worked! Don't forget to mark your question as answered so that others know this worked